# validation not being applied when input type button element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The issue is viewable on the following webpage - http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/test/

I am trying to apply various validation rules to the form that features on the web page mentioned above with a jQuery plugin that utilises custom data attributes (http://formvalidator.net/index.html). This validation is present on the first 5 form fields. This is viewable when a user focuses on a field and then progresses to the next field, the previous field will lose focus and a validation message is presented.

I am encountering an issue whereby the validation is not applied when the form is submitted. This is caused by the `onclick` and `type` attributes that are present on the `<input>` element

```
<input class="btn-wpbc" type="button" onclick="mybooking_submit(this.form,1, 'en_US' );" value="Send">
```

I have observed that if the `type` attribute is changed to `type="submit"` and the `onclick` attribute is removed in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools then the validation will be applied to the form fields.

However changing the attributes will in result the failure of calender validation as a booking is being made through an AJAX request that is initialised through the following JavaScript:

`onclick="mybooking_submit(this.form,1, 'en_US' );"`

The form will no longer check that a day has been selected.

Are there any suggestions for ensuring both forms of validation take effect (calender day selected and validation on form fields)?

Comment: may be it should be 
onclick="return mybooking_submit(this.form,1, 'en_US' );"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change input **type** attribute to submit and call  your javascript function on onsubmit event on form tag. Like-

```
<form onsubmit="mybooking_submit(this.form,1, 'en_US' );" >
```